# Can't remotely connect to server with hostname, IP address works- CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, dns, centos-7

I just installed CentOS 7 and configured my network as given [here](http://www.tecmint.com/things-to-do-after-minimal-rhel-centos-7-installation/#C2.)

When I did cat /etc/resolv.conf, I got:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver <IP address>
```

So I guess I have only one DNS and included only DNS1="" in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp5s0 file.

When I do route -n, I get:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         <IP Address-1>      0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp5s0
<IP Address-2>      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp5s0
```

I am assuming my gateway is IP Address-1 above and updated the same in config file. Now my /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp5s0 looks like:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp5s0"
UUID="ae988f3f-1fdb-4613-a7bc-c43fb8076c15"
DEVICE="enp5s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="172.XX.X.XX"
PREFIX="24"
GATEWAY="172.XX.X.X"
DNS1="172.XX.X.X" 
DNS2="172.XX.X.X"
```

Both DNS1, DNS2 are same as Gateway.

My /etc/resolv.conf looks like:
`# Generated by NetworkManager
domain hom
search home
nameserver 172.XX.X.X`

After updating all these values and naming my machine centos7 in /etc/hostname file, I am not able to connect to the machine with `ssh user_name@hostname` but `ssh user_name@172.XX.X.XX` works. Also, after the machine logs in, the prompt looks like: `[user_name@hostname ~]$`

We do have other machines running Centos 6 and donot have such issues. We use host names for remote connection to those. I am having this problem only with centOS 7. Also, when i do `host <IP ADDRESS>`, all other machines show their hostnames but Centos 7 doesnot. It just says `new-host-23.home`

Not sure if this is a machine issue or a DNS issue.
I did not find my solution in another similar question on Stack overflow. Someone please help me.

Comment: are you able to ping 
```centos7```?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure if the following value is correct:

```
domain hom
```

Then, perform a simple network test on your SSH client machine:

```
nslookup <centos7_hostname>
```

A positive result should be similar as follow:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  216.58.221.100
```

If you cannot get a successful response from NSLOOKUP, you need to check if a relevant DNS record is stored at your local DNS server.

Comment: Thanks, I got something strange here:
`nslookup <centos7_hostname>` gives: `Name: centos7` `Address 1: some other IP Address`. the IP Address I am getting here is not what I see when I do `ifconfig` on the centos7 machine.

Comment: Then you have to check the record of your DNS server to see if it is pointed to the correct IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You have put:

```
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
```

But it should be:

```
BOOTPROTO="none"
```

With your config, you are still using DHCP, so it is not strange that you get another IP... because your IP settings is ignored.